# What does the present perfect mean to you in this sentence "They have seen this cartoon many times"?

Tags: present-perfect

> "They **have seen** this cartoon many times"?

If I'm not mistaken, the phrase conveys the idea of an action that
was completely completed in the past and has been repeated many times.

I wonder if that sentence sounds like the action could be repeated again. That is, does it sound like the action could keep repeating itself?

This question is important to me because I'm trying to find accurate ways to translate that sentence into my language (Brazilian Portuguese). I would like to know how it sounds especially for native speakers.

The fact that that action sounds like it can be repeated can give me clues on how to translate it properly, so this information is extremely important.

Does the sentence sound as if the action of watching the cartoons could keep repeating itself, or does it sound as if the action has already been completed many times and now cannot be repeated anymore?

Any other descriptions you guys can give me are welcome.
Thank you!

Comment: A 70-year-old woman could quite naturally say *I have given birth many times* without implying that she will do it again, if that clears things up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker is making a connection to the present.  In this case the connection is that they are talking about the experiences that they currently have.  They have memories and they have opinions about the cartoon now.

They are not talking about the time or the situation in the past when they saw the cartoon, and they give no indication about when they saw it. If they wanted to talk about the past, they would use the past tense:

> I saw that cartoon many times while I was living in Kuwait last year.

They also give no indication about the future, except insofar as their current state of having seen the cartoons will continue into the future. It doesn't give any information about future actions, such as watching the cartoon again.

Pragmatically, (and using common sense) there's no reason to suppose that the cartoon couldn't be seen in the future, but there's no reason to be certain that it will be.

This might be called the experiential use of the present perfect. It is used to talk about experiences that you have resulting from past actions.